# Audio is no longer working on iPad3

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5.1

I've got two reports from users of my app, running iOS 5.1.1 on iPad 3 (iPad 1 & 2 are working fine), that the audio is no longer working.

I'm using the AVAudioPlayer from the AVFoundation library.

Is anybody else experiencing any similar problems.

What  to do now?

Comment: The audio file is not working on Simulator , device or both ?

Comment: Audio working fine on simulator as well as on ipad, ipod, iPhone4s problem is on iPad3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also give this code for your audioPlayer

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Hope it will solve your issue.